# Nested class definition outside outer class's, while outer class contains instance of inner class

Tags: c++, nested, inner-classes, nested-class, outer-classes

**C++**

How can I put the definition of an inner (nested) class outside its outer (enclosing) class's definition, where the outer class has at least one instance of the inner class as a data member? I searched but the most relevant SO answer I found, [Nested Class Definition in source file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4482005/nested-class-definition-in-source-file/4482013#4482013), does not have an example where the outer class has an inner object as a data member. I followed that answer, as far as declaring but not defining the inner class inside the outer class's definition is concerned, but my code is still broken:

```
struct Outer
{
    struct Inner;
    Inner myinner;
    Outer() : myinner(2) {}
};

struct Outer::Inner
{
    Inner(int n) : num(n) {}
    int num;
};

int main()
{
    Outer myouter;
}
```

It gives the error `error C2079: 'Outer::myinner' uses undefined struct 'Outer::Inner'` in VC11.

And why doesn't the broken code have an effect equivalent to that of the version in which `Inner` is defined within `Outer`'s definition, like in the following working code?

```
struct Outer
{
    struct Inner
    {
        Inner(int n) : num(n) {}
        int num;
    } myinner;
    Outer() : myinner(2) {}
};
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a red flag, but you can do it using a fake template.

```
template< typename = void >
struct Outer_temp
{
    struct Inner;
    Inner myinner;
    Outer_temp() : myinner(2) {}
};

typedef Outer_temp<> Outer; // Hide template from user.

template< typename v >
struct Outer_temp< v >::Inner
{
    Inner(int n) : num(n) {}
    int num;
};

int main()
{
    Outer myouter;
}
```

`Inner` inside the template is a dependent type, so it does not need to be complete as you define an instance, in a member or any other context. It only needs to be complete once the instantiation happens, in this case from `main`.

I can't imagine a good reason to do this, but there it is.

Nested classes should not be used for the sake of program organization. Nesting suggests a conceptual dependency, "Inner cannot exist except in a context provided by Outer." Although it is common, for example, for a container node class to be nested within the container, this can cause problems. The SCARY idiom is a design style that repudiates such organization and gains improved genericity.

TL;DR: define the two classes independently and link them with a nested `typedef`.

Comment: +1 for working code. I understand your template syntax. But I don’t know why it works with your fake template but not with my non-template. Can't say I'm a template expert. By `"Inner inside the template is a dependent type, so it does not need to be complete as you define an instance, in a member or any other context. It only needs to be complete once the instantiation happens”` do you mean my `Inner` is an independent type and incomplete at the time it is instantiated within `Outer`?

Comment: @CodeBricks "dependent" refers to depending on the parameters to the template. "What is inner? It depends what specialization this is." A templates can be instantiated using types declared after itself because templates are allowed to refer to incomplete types and such, as long as they depend on a parameter. I introduced such a false dependency to defer compilation of `Inner myinner` until `main`.

Comment: Why can't the declaration of `Inner` in my code defer the compilation until `Outer` sees `Inner`'s definition below `Outer`'s? It seems to work with regular functions. Example: `void g(); void f(){g();} void(g){cout<<"hi\n";}`

Comment: @CodeBricks You can call a function with only a declaration, no definition. You cannot instantiate a class until it is defined. If you used `Inner *myinner` inside `Outer` the problem would never have occurred because defining a pointer doesn't require a definition. But pointer arithmetic `++myinner` would require a definition. There are just a lot of rules :P

Comment: In your answer, what do you mean by "define the two classes independently and link them with a nested `typedef`"? Do you mean this: `struct Outer { /*...*/ typedef Inner itd; /*...*/}; struct Inner {/*...*/};`? If so, then why? If you want `Inner` to be nonexistent outside `Outer`, how does that help `Inner` be more or less accessible outside `Outer`? Wouldn't accessibility to `Inner`'s members depend only on `Inner`'s access modifiers regardless of which class uses its instance as a data member? Or did you not mean to put the word "nested" there? Were you simply referring to your code above?

Comment: @CodeBricks This is my point: class nesting doesn't implement interface (in)visibility. It should reflect conceptual possibility in implementation terms. You might compromise a little and let the user have a class they can name but cannot instantiate, using `friend`.